# Google map missing alt of image causing lower accessibility

Tags: google-maps, accessibility, alt

How can we add blank `alt tags` to the Google map tiles (generated by v3 api) so that they do not lower our accessibility score?

[image: Example Image]

Comment: You can't. It would also be pointless, why do you care about dinner arbitrary score? Build your website in a way disabled people can use it. Or don't care about a score.

Answer (score 3):

It would be unwise to attempt to do what you are suggesting. By attempting to "improve" the score that your automated tool is giving you, you would almost certainly be degrading accessibility for actual humans.

The issue here is that embedded Google Maps are not accessible for non-sighted visitors, full-stop. Doing hacky things with JavaScript won't fix that. To the best of my knowledge, none of the major interactive maps are very accessible. Here are [a few of the reasons why](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/accessible/C5jN4m5cbuQ).

If you genuinely are concerned about the accessibility of your webpage, and not just an arbitrary number that some tool gives you, then there are a few things you can do:

1. Understand that non-sighted visitors won't be able to use interactive maps. Offer alternatives instead, like text directions. Clearly state any relevant addresses in the text of the page.
2. If your page contains embedded maps, you may wish to hide that content from screen reader users with the [aria-hidden attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute).
3. The Google Maps web interface offers a reasonably OK level of accessibility when it comes to directions between two points. The directions URLs are of the format: `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Rockefeller+Plaza,+New+York,+NY+10111`.
4. Use techniques that make use of special markup that is [only announced to screen reader users](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/).
5. Keep in mind that you are creating webpages for actual humans, not robots.
6. Test your pages using free tools, like NVDA or VoiceOver with more than one browser.